# How to filter unique columns in a table in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which looks like this;

```
col1 - col2

data1 - ip1
data1 - ip2
data2 - ip2
```

So this `ip2` belongs to `data1` and `data2` but `ip1` only belongs to `data1` so I want to filter `ip1` only. In other words, I want to list every item inside `col2` column which only has unique content which is belong to `data1`. If the same `ip*` belongs to more than one `data*` then don't filter that.

Example in SQL;

```sql
SELECT col2 FROM table1 WHERE col1 = 'data1' AND (if col1 is unique and doesn't belong to any other data.nth)
```

So the part in parentheses is what I can't figure out how to do. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select col2
from table1
group by col2
having min(col1) = 'data1' and min(col1) = max(col1);
```